# Programmatically use iptables-restore when special character exists in log-prefix

Tags: linux, iptables

I am writing a program that takes a snapshot of iptable rules so that they can be restored at a later point. I don't want to write the rules to a file; I store them as a string in my code.

This worked perfectly making a call out to `iptables-save` and capturing the output into a string and then calling `iptables-restore` combined with bash process substitution to feed the rules string back into iptables e.g. `iptables-restore <(echo "<rules here>")` (have to change this later though to use pipes since Ubuntu won't support that)

I encountered a case where there was a `log-prefix` option with a space on one of the rules that has caused the restore step to break. For example:

```
[root@host ~]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
```

and the output of `iptables-save`:

```
[root@host ~]# iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.8 (nf_tables) on Wed May  3 21:45:25 2023
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [101:5876]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [84:34334]
-A OUTPUT -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed May  3 21:45:25 2023
```

This is the command run by the code:

```
/bin/sh -c /sbin/iptables-restore <(echo "# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.8 (nf_tables) on Wed May  3 21:45:25 2023
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [1936:94741]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [612:2005831]
-A OUTPUT -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed May  3 21:45:25 2023
")
Bad argument `BLOCK]'
Error occurred at line: 6
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
```

If I remove the space between `UFW` and `BLOCK` it works ok.

I've tried escaping the quotation marks in the string too but still the same issue.

Is there some trick to get this to work. Also, I don't have any control of what could be in the rules and they need to be replaced exactly as taken from the snapshot so preprocessing the string before calling restore wouldn't work for me.

Comment: What are your constraints here? Why are you dumping iptables output to a bash commandline as opposed to a file or pipe?

Comment: Or get rid of UFW ... it's an abomination anyway.

Comment: I prefer to keep the tables in memory as it is harder for someone to tamper with them. As I mentioned in the question, I'll need to change to a pipe since ubuntu (dash) doesn't support the process substitution that I was relying on.

Comment: It would help greatly to understand why `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore` won't work for you. What is it you are trying to accomplish aside from reinventing a slightly different wheel?

Comment: I was trying to take a snapshot of the tables and have them stored in my program without writing them to a file (requirement not controlled by me). At some point later on, it should be possible to roll back to this snapshot, again not writing to a file first. `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore` do work for me when calling them from the code except there was an edge case where rules contained quotations. The solution was to make a pass over the rules string in memory and properly escape the quotations before passing it back to `iptables-restore`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems after bouncing the issue off a few people in the office I actually have it working. The solution of escaping the quotations was correct e.g. `\"[UFW BLOCK] \"`. I had thought it wasn't working because I was monitoring the output of the command:

```
/bin/sh -c /sbin/iptables-restore <(echo "# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.8 (nf_tables) on Wed May  3 22:15:05 2023
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [258:20165]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [210:104923]
-A OUTPUT -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix \"[UFW BLOCK] \"
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed May  3 22:15:05 2023
")
```

which has the escape characters present but when running iptables list I see they are not there:

```
[root@host ~]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
```

Apologies for the dumb moment doh!

Answer (score 0):

You did not show any C++ code, but instead of relying on fragile bash argument handling you could use a pipe and use the `/dev/fd/X` syntax:

```
int pipefd[2];
int ret = pipe(pipefd);
if (ret != 0) { /* handle error */ }
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid != 0) {
  /* parent */
  close(pipefd[0]);
  write(pipefd[1], stored_iptables.c_str(), stored_iptables.length());
  int wstatus = 0;
  waitpid(pid, &wstatus, 0);
} else {
  /* child */
  close(pipefd[1]);
  std::string path = std::string{"/dev/fd/"} + std::to_string(pipefd[0]);
  execl("/sbin/iptables-restore", "/sbin/iptables-restore", path.c_str(), NULL);
}
```

To simplify further, you could use `mkstemp` to generate an anonymous temporary file, dump data into it, and again pass `/dev/fd/X` to iptables-restore.

EDIT: the mkstemp solution (equally untested):

```
int fd = mkstemp("iptables.XXXXXX");
write(fd, stored_iptables.c_str(), stored_iptables.length());
lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
std::string path = std::string{"/dev/fd/"} + std::to_string(pipefd[0]);
execl("/sbin/iptables-restore", "/sbin/iptables-restore", path.c_str(), NULL);
```

Comment: Interesting, my solution to cover cases where process substitution wouldn't work was to do something similar but using bash e.g. `rules | /sbin/iptables-restore /dev/stdin`. I'll try the code version and see if it will work also.

Comment: one of the reasons for avoiding file writes (even temporary ones) is SELinux can block it. Also, I tried out your example and it seems it won't be so straight forward. `iptables-restore` has multi levels of symlink that seem to cause a problem. e.g. on my RHEL9 box it eventually lands on `/sbin/xtables-nft-multi` and that would require some additional logic e.g. if we have nft then the command needs to change to `/sbin/iptables-restore iptables-restore /dev/fd/0` otherwise you get the error `ERROR: No valid subcommand given.` .  This doesn't happen when invoking via bash strangely enough

Comment: Your example had `/sbin/iptables-restore ...` as a bash commandline. That corresponds to `execve("/sbin/iptables-restore", "/sbin/iptables-restore", "...")`. [One piece of documentation](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/iptables/xtables-nft-multi.8.en.html) suggests that arg0 is being used to work out which subcommand to use, so this should work